# TripleDES Encryption result different in C# and Node JS

Tags: c#, node.js, cryptojs, tripledes

This might be a possible duplicate but I am unable to fix it.
Below is my code in C# for tripleDES:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class MainClass {
   public static void Main (string[] args) {

   String encrypt="5241110000602040";
   SymmetricAlgorithm sa= SymmetricAlgorithm.Create("TripleDES");
   sa.Key= Convert.FromBase64String("FRSF1P3b6fHiW/DXrK8ZJks5KAiyNpP0");
   sa.IV=Convert.FromBase64String("YFKA0QlomKY=");


   byte[] iba=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encrypt);
   MemoryStream mS=new MemoryStream();

   ICryptoTransform trans=sa.CreateEncryptor();
   byte[] buf= new byte[2049];

   CryptoStream cs=new CryptoStream(mS,trans,CryptoStreamMode.Write);

   cs.Write(iba,0,iba.Length);
   cs.FlushFinalBlock();

   Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(mS.ToArray()));


 }
}
```

Encrypted value is

> Nj7GeyrbJB93HZLplFZwq5HRjxnvZSvU

I want to achieve the same thing with crypto-js library of nodejs. Here is nodejs code of what I tried:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

var text = "5241110000602040";
var key = "FRSF1P3b6fHiW/DXrK8ZJks5KAiyNpP0";

var options = {
//  mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, 
//  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("YFKA0QlomKY=")
};

var textWordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text);
var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);

var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(textWordArray, keyHex, options);

var base64String = encrypted.toString();

console.log('encrypted val: ' + base64String);
```

Expected output

> Nj7GeyrbJB93HZLplFZwq5HRjxnvZSvU

Actual Output

> NXSBe9YEiGs5p6VHkzezfdcb5o08bALB

Encrypted value in nodejs is different than C#. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do both languages end up with the same key and IV? You should check that first.

Comment: `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("YFKA0QlomKY=")` shouldn't work -- that's not a hex string, it's Base64. (Hence, unsurprisingly, `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Tried that but still encrypted output is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You differently decode key and iv.

In c# you use base64:

```
sa.Key= Convert.FromBase64String("FRSF1P3b6fHiW/DXrK8ZJks5KAiyNpP0");
sa.IV=Convert.FromBase64String("YFKA0QlomKY=");
```

in node.js hex:

```
iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("YFKA0QlomKY=")
var key = "FRSF1P3b6fHiW/DXrK8ZJks5KAiyNpP0";
var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
```

Try to use base64 in both cases.